# Barcode Scanner error "unfortunately app has stopped"

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to make a simple app on barcode scanner using phonegap.
Here is the html file for that. I am getting an error "Android java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo" in the logcat and the app closes with error
"unfortunately app has stopped". Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-     scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>My Barcode/QR Code Scanner</title>
    <style>
        body{
             background:#888888 none repeat scroll 0 0;
        }
        input[type='text']{
            width:18em;
            border:1px solid black;
        }
        input[type='button']{
            width:20em;
            border:1px solid black;
            color:#ffffff;
            font-family:"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
            font-size:0.9em;
            font-weight:bold;
            background:#737CA1;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function scanCode(){
            window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
                function(result){
                    alert("Scanned Code: " + result.text 
                    + ". Format: " + result.format
                    + ". Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
                }, 
                function(error){
                    alert("Scan failed: " + error);
                }
            );
        }

        function encodeData(){
            var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
            if (data != ''){
                cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.encode(
                    BarcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE, data, 
                    function(success){
                        alert("Encode success: " + success);
                    }, 
                    function(fail){
                        alert("Encoding failed: " + fail);
                    }
                );
            }
            else{
                alert("Please enter some data.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Barcode/QR Code Scanner And Encoder</h3>

    <input type="button" value="Scan Code" onclick="scanCode();"/><br/><br/>

    Data : <br/>
    <input type="text" name="data" id="data" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Encode Data" onclick="encodeData();"/>
</body>
```

Comment: I found the answer here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333436/phonegap-barcodescanner-encode-function-stops-app> Hope this works for you!